# How can I make this script better?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

This is what I have, I'm trying create panels that have car models on them. When you click the heading link I want the corresponding panel to slide in or out. It's working but I feel like my code is probably very bad.

```
 /* START OF MODEL BAR */

                /* END OF MODEL BAR */
```

How can I make my code more efficient? I feel like I'm repeating myself.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: is uncomprehending as you have been able to accept the other answer. Bah!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you see code that repeats itself, turn it into a function:

```
var registerClickHandler = function(id, classToAdd) {
    $(id).click(function() {
        $('.carActive').removeClass('carActive');
        $(classToAdd).addClass('carActive');
    });
}
```

Then this:

```
 $('#sedans').click(function() {
 $('.carActive').removeClass('carActive');
 $('#panel2-1').addClass('carActive');
 });
 $('#suv').click(function() {
 $('#panel2-2').addClass('carActive');
 $('.carActive').removeClass('carActive');    
 });
 $('#vert a').click(function() {
 $('.carActive').removeClass('carActive');
 $('#panel2-3').addClass('carActive');
 });
 $('#hybrid a').click(function() {
 $('.carActive').removeClass('carActive');
 $('#panel2-4').addClass('carActive');
 });
 $('#sport a').click(function() {
 $('.carActive').removeClass('carActive');
 $('#panel2-5').addClass('carActive');
 });
```

Turns into this:

```
registerClickHandler('#sedans', '#panel2-1');
registerClickHandler('#suv', '#panel2-2');
registerClickHandler('#vert a', '#panel2-3');
registerClickHandler('#hybrid a', '#panel2-4');
registerClickHandler('#sport a', '#panel2-');
```

Or even this:

```
var options = [
  {'#sedans': '#panel2-1'},
  {'#suv': '#panel2-2'},
  {'#vert a': '#panel2-3'},
  {'#hybrid a': '#panel2-4'},
  {'#sport a': '#panel2-'}
];

options.forEach(registerClickHandler)
```

Comment: So, if in a second moment he want to add a car-div, he had to remember to register an handler to the car.. uhm..

Answer (score 2):

You can you use this way instance:

```
/* use JQuery class selector */
$('.carType').on('click', foo);

var foo = function() {
   $(this).removeClass('carActive');
   var target = $(this).children('a').attr('href');
   $(target).addClass('carActive');
}
```

Comment: Hm, for some reason this isn't working. Does the target inherit the links '#' symbol?

Answer (score 0):

Event delegation mechanism is another alternative (and to me the best choice in such a situation). It do not rely on ids but on the html structure itself ..

```
// attach the event to the first common ancestor holding #sedans, #suv, #vert, #hybrid and #sport ... Then no need to hard code ids, you can even add entry via ajax and it will still work
    $('dl.tabs').on('click', function(e){
        var $dd = $(e.target).closest('dd'),
            $a = $dd.find('a');
        if($a.length){
            var ids = $.map(
                $.makeArray($dd.parent().find('a[href^="#panel"]')),
                function(el, i){ return $(el).attr('href'); }
            ).join(','); // This build a selector of all panels linked inside the menu
            $(ids).add($dd.siblings()).removeClass('carActive')
                .filter($a[0].hash).add($dd).addClass('carActive');
            // e.preventDefault(); you may want to prevent the browser to scroll to the anchor id
        }
    });
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/stphane/9C7K8/)